# jquery more button issue

Tags: php, jquery, function, comments

I'm tryin to implement a jquery/ajax pagination system for my comments. I've already implemented a jquery delete and insert comment feature. Now i'm having trouble fully implementing the pagination part. Some of my code is below. Basically, in the function load more posts, i want the variable count to reset to zero if the user either clicks the delete comment button or the insert comment button. The id's for these buttons are respectively, 'deletecomment' and 'addcomment'. essentially the count variable is being passed to a query where with LIMIT $page, 5. Please help if you can. Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 0;
    var commentcount = "<?= $commentcount ?>";
    if(commentcount <= 5){
        $("#more").hide();
    }
    if(commentcount >= 6){
        $("#more").show();
    }
    $("#more").click(loadPosts);

    function loadPosts() {
        var num = 5;
        $(".loading").show("fast");
        count += num;
        $.post("pull.php?id=<? echo $id; ?>", {'page': count}, function(data){
            $("#commentarea").append(data);
            $(".loading").hide("slow");
            var commentcount = "<?= $commentcount ?>";
            if(commentcount <= (count + num) && count >=5){
                $("#more").hide();
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In loadPosts you have:

```
var commentcount = "<?= $commentcount ?>";
```

The PHP code gets run when the page is first loaded, not on the AJAX request. So when the loadPosts function runs, the commentcount is set to the same as its current value.

You probably want to return JSON data from your pull.php instead... something like:

```
$commentcount = /* however you get your count */;
$returnData = array( 'commentcount' => $commentcount, 'comments' => $comments );
echo json_encode( $returnData );
```

Then in your JS:

```
$('#commentarea').append( data.comments );
var commentcount = data.commentcount;
```

Comment: thanks for the response, so basically i can compare this commentcount to the commentcount that was run originally, and if they are different i can set count = 0 again in the function?

Comment: sorry this is my first time using json. do i have to download a library of some sort to reference? I tried the above. except now the comments wont append even.

Comment: No, `json_encode` is a builtin PHP function. jQuery might not be automatically recognizing that the returned data is JSON and not HTML - try adding `data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);` to the top of your callback. And make sure your PHP doesn't output anything else - the `echo json_encode` needs to be the only output from the script. Anything you were outputting before should instead be added to `$comments` so it can be returned as JSON.

Comment: `function(data){
            data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
   $("#commentarea").append( data.comment );`

    pull.php: ...
    `$comment.="<tr><td colspan='2'>$commenttext<br/><br/></td></tr></table></div>";
    
 
 
 $returnData = array( 'commentcount' => $commentcount, 'comment' => $comment );
echo json_encode( $returnData );
`

Thats snippets of my code. right now when i press load more, the the loading text keeps flashing. Im prolly makin a stupid mistake. I know the comment variable has no error because i tested that output before.

Comment: what if i did this :

`$.post('script.php', data, function(response) {
    // Do something with the request
}, 'json');` ?

Comment: Yes, telling jQuery to use JSON data may help as well. You should probably try using Firebug to examine the AJAX response and make sure it looks right - if it's good JSON, there will be a JSON tab with nicely formatted output.